# How do I add a git submodule in a non empty directory?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am trying to add a submodule in a non empty folder inside a repo with:

```
git submodule add repo_path.git non_empty_folder
```

I get the following message:

```
'non_empty_folder' already exists and is not a valid git repo
```

Is it possible to force the creation of the submodule? Thanks!

Comment: What result are you trying to achieve? A folder where "imported" files would be mixed with the files from your own project? I'm affraid, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a new `submodule` repo outside your main project repository.
- Rsync files from the directory which you want to make a submodule in your main project.
- Commit these files into submodule repo and push it to origin.
- `git remove` all files in the submodule directory in main project
- Commit changes in main project
- Now you are ready to create a submodule

A word of caution.  I would highly suggest using a visual tool like SourceTree to help you manage submodules.  It is an advanced feature of git and if not managed properly will give you plenty of grief.  On a flip side, if used properly it is very powerful and can help you avoid code duplication.